# Why do I get an error in FOREACH loop using Template?

Tags: perl, templates, template-toolkit

I need help with this problem, I am struggling from last 15days please help me.I have xml file and I stored in a variable using XML::simple. I processed through template toolkit. I am getting error like this

```
$var1={
 university=>{
      'name'=>'svu',
       'location'=>'ravru',
        'branch'=>{
                 'electronics'=>{
                            'student'=>[
                                     {
                                    'name'=>'mikky',
                                     'number'=>'12',
                                       'semester'=>{
                                              'Number'=>'1',
                                              'subjects'=>'7',
                                               'rank'=>'1'
                                              }
                                           },
                                   {
                                    'name'=>'vijju',
                                     'number'=>'15',
                                       'semester'=>[
                                            {
                                           'number'=>'1',
                                            'subjects'=>'7',
                                             'rank'=>'10'
                                              },
                                             {
                                            'number'=>'1',
                                            'subjects'=>'7',
                                             'rank'=>'1'
                                              }
                                             ]
                                           },
                                          {
                                    'name'=>'shyam',
                                     'number'=>'16',
                                       'semester'=>[
                                            {
                                           'number'=>'1',
                                            'subjects'=>'7',
                                             'rank'=>'2'
                                              },
                                             {
                                            'number'=>'2',
                                            'subjects'=>'4',
                                             'rank'=>'2'
                                              }
                                             ]
                                           }
                                         }
                                      ]
                                     }
                                   };
           university=>{
                 'name'=>'sku',
                'location'=>'ANTP',
                  'branch'=>{
                        'electronics'=>{
                                  'student'=>[
                                            {
                                          'name'=>'xxx',
                                           'number'=>'12',
                                          'semester'=>{
                                                  'Number'=>'3',
                                                    'subjects'=>'6',
                                                  'rank'=>'20'
                                              }
                                           },
                                   {
                                    'name'=>'xxx',
                                     'number'=>'6',
                                       'semester'=>[
                                            {
                                           'number'=>'1',
                                            'subjects'=>'9',
                                             'rank'=>'12'
                                              },
                                             {
                                            'number'=>'2',
                                            'subjects'=>'4',
                                             'rank'=>'2'
                                              }
                                             ]
                                           }
                                         }
                                      ]
                                     }
                                   };
      'studentaddres'=>{
                 'address'=>[
                            {
                           'name'=>'mikky',
                           'number'=>'12',
                           'adress'=>' badvel,kadapa,a.p,india',
                            },

                           {
                           'name'=>'vijju',
                           'number'=>'15',
                           'adress'=>' raipur,ananthapur,a.p,india',
                            },

                           {
                           'name'=>'shyam',
                           'number'=>'16',
                           'adress'=>' raighad,rajsthan,india',
                            },
                          ]
                       }
```

(New comment: I have the data like this, If We look into deep I have the same name and number in student element and also in address element, I have one more thing adress in address element. now I need to search student name and number in address element and get the address of that student. Some times I have same  names with different numbers so I need to search both number and name for student address.)

and I processed like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; 
use XML::Simple;
use XML::Fast;
use Template;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");
print Dumper($data);
my $template = Template->new();
my $filename = 'output.tex';
$template->process(\*DATA, $data, $filename)
    || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";

system( "pdflatex $filename" );
__DATA__
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
\begin{document}

[% FOREACH st IN university %]
[% st.name %] 
[%st.location%]
studentdata:
[% FOREACH student IN st.branch.electronics.student %]
Component type: [%+ student.name +%][%+ student.number +%]
[% FOREACH semester IN student.semester %]
[%+ semester.number +%]
[%+ semester.subjects +%]
[%+  semester.rank +%]
[% END %]
[% END %]
[% END %]

\end{document}
```

But I getting Different output rather than what I want. After executing this script I am getting output when I have three or more students in electronics and two or more semesters for each student then only I am getting. otherwise it does print any thing just printing studentdata: three times . for example if I have one student with one semester in university at that situation it doesn't give any thing it printing like this

```
       studentdata:
           studentdata:
            studentdata:
```

why for loop is executing like that, I can't understand really what wrong win the for loop but I need to print like this

```
name:
      svu
location: 
      ravru
student data:
   student name=xxx  number=12
  semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=2
   student name=xxx  number=15
  semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=10
 semester number=2 subjects=4 rank=1
 student name=xxx  number=16
 semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=2
 semester number=2 subjects=4 rank=2

#!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;
 use Data::Dumper; 
 use XML::Simple;
 use XML::Fast;
 use Template;

 my $studentaddres;

  my $xml = new XML::Simple;
 my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml", ForceArray=>1);
  print Dumper($data);

 my $template = Template->new();
   my $filename = 'output.tex';
   $template->process(\*DATA, $data, $filename)
 || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";

 $studentaddres->{by_student_number} 
 = { map { $_->{number} => $_ } @{ $studentaddres->{address} }};

 system( "pdflatex $filename" );
  __DATA__
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
   \begin{document}

 [% FOREACH st IN university %]
  [% st.name %] 
   [%st.location%]
  studentdata:
  [% FOREACH student IN st.branch.electronics.student %]
    Component type: [%+ student.name +%][%+ student.number +%]

  [% address = studentaddres.by_student_number.item( student.number );
  IF address %]
 [% address.adress %]
 [% END %]
 [% FOREACH semester IN student.semester %]
  [%+ semester.number +%]
   [%+ semester.subjects +%]
   [%+  semester.rank +%]
    [% END %]
   [% END %]
   [% END %]

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your data is not valid perl. Secondly, iterating through a hash gives you a (Java-like) "entry" objects. So 'st' => { key => 'name', value => 'svu' }. Thus `st.name` is nothing.

This is more like what you want (or what works, anyway ):

```
name:
      [% university.name %] 
location:
      [% university.location %]
studentdata:
   [%- FOREACH student IN university.branch.electronics.student %]
      student name=[% student.name %] number=[% student.number %]
       [%- FOREACH semester IN student.semester %]
     semester number=[% semester.number %] subjects=[% semester.subjects 
           %] rank=[% semester.rank %]
       [%- END -%]
   [%- END -%]
```

And I had to change 'semester' on student #12 to be an array and de-capitalize 'number'. This is what you had:

```
   'semester'=>{
          'Number'=>'1',
          'subjects'=>'7',
           'rank'=>'1'
          }
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
   'semester'=>[{
          'number'=>'1',
          'subjects'=>'7',
           'rank'=>'1'
          }]
```

Without semester as an array, you were just iterating through this type of thing again:

```
( { key => 'number',   value => '1' }
, { key => 'subjects', value => '7' }
, { key => 'rank',     value => '1' } 
)
```

And not necessarily (or even *likely*) in that order.

Using a properly closed `$var1` as the data, the code I put above gives me:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
   \begin{document}

name:
      svu 
location:
      ravru
studentdata:
      student name=xxx number=12
     semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=1
      student name=xxx number=15
     semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=10
     semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=1
      student name=xxx number=16
     semester number=1 subjects=7 rank=2
     semester number=2 subjects=4 rank=2
  \end{document}
```

To debug your script, you might want to make the following changes:

```
my $template = Template->new( { EVAL_PERL => 1 } );
```

And then, where you want to see the structure that you're addressing, do this:

```
 [% RAWPERL %]
 use Data::Dumper ();
 print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $stash->get( 'semester' ) ], [ 'semester' ] ), "\n";
 [% END %]
```

You'll quickly see when the hash in semester has no number, subjects, or rank fields.

---

(Answering comment) Well, if you have some students with addresses as some without, you could do the following:

```
[% IF student.address;
    addr = student.address; %][%-
    -%]Address: [% addr.lines.1 %]
                [% addr.lines.2 %]
                [% addr.city %], [% addr.state %] [% addr.zip %]
[% END %]
```

Or if you had a hash of addresses, you could do the following.

```
[% IF address_for_student.exists( student.number );
     address = address_for_student.item( student.number );
     %]
...
[% END %]
```

---

(Answering new address part of question)

You *can* massage your data before presentation. This is what I suggest *before* passing the data to the presentation layer. (Here `$studentaddres` is just a reference to the structure in the stash.)

```
$studentaddres->{by_student_number} 
    = { map { $_->{number} => $_ } @{ $studentaddres->{address} }}
    ;
```

Then, in the presentation layer you can just do this:

```
[% address = studentaddres.by_student_number.item( student.number );
   IF address %]
   ...
[% END %]
```

In general, you should have the links that you need *prior* to the presentation layer, that makes the presentation layer just a matter of displaying the data.

XML stores your model. Fine. XML does trees just fine, but doesn't do complex graphs too well. So if you have complex relationships (and XML::Simple is not going to know *anything* about those) you have to use this type of algorithmic model: **retrieve → link → display**. You have to do this with YAML or JSON or even rows pulled from a database, so the link stage is second-nature to me.

The presentation layer is the wrong layer for *searching*. It should just handle lists of 0, 1, or many or simple cases like relationship exists-or-not.

Comment: I have 15 university's so I written for loop for getting all university's and I am getting all values but my problem is in second for loop. I am not able to get student elements as I want. That for loop executing three times if one student and one semester in electronics.If I have two or more students and two or more semesters in electronics it printing exactly.I don't know why this problem.

Comment: @pavini, as I said. 1) your data is bad, 2) you are iterating through hashes. You went round three times because there are three keys. See the changes I made to student #12.

Comment: ,Hi sorry for asking once again my question is in my student element I have number and name, and also i have same data student name and number with address. I need to search each student name and number in that data if match found then get the address and print along with student name and number. can you suggest me what should i do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply,I tried as you said but its not working, If you don't mind I edited my question clearly and added my question as new comment. Can you have a look at comment and suggest me please, because I am very beginner to use template toolkit.

Comment: I edited your post it means I posted my code what I did after your suggestion but its not working. Thank you very much for spending your valuable time on me.